# Flutter round Underlineinput border

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I get the underline on the TextField like this?

[image]

Comment: do you want to show this just when it get focused ?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this my making a transparent `TextField`, thn wrap it with `stack` then add a Container with border radius wrapped with `Positionned` to th stack, it can something like this :

```
Stack(
  children: [
     yourTextField(),
     Positioned(
        bottom:0,
     child: 
        Container(width:double.infinity,
  height: 4,
   decoration: 
  BoxDecoration(borderRadius: 
  BorderRadius.circular(15), color: 
  Colors.red) 
 ) 
 ) 
 ]
  )
```

I didn't test it since I write it with phone but this will give you better approach
Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Use `UnderlineInputBorder` for border prperties inside of the InputDecoration, example:

```
enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan),   
                  ),
```

You can specify the border style also for errorBorder, focusBorder..

Comment: He wants to give radius to that underline.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan, width: 3),
                ),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan, width: 3),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Comment: He wants to give radius to that underline.